# Naming convention for images in a large website

Tags: image, web, naming-conventions

This is a question about organising lots of images in a web project. Say you had the following two icons in a web project that represeneted, for example, a product selected or a product not selected:

[image: product selected icons]

What would you name them?

Seems a simple question, but I suspect naming images is something of an art.

For example:

- **star_active.png and star_inactive.png**: Seems fair enough but what if you want to replace the star at a later date with a circle say. Then your name is misleading so you would have to rename it and then update all your css etc.
- **product_selected.png and product_unselected.png**: Great for the when used for the specific action of selecting a product but what if I wanted to use the same image for a different purpose. Then the name is confusing and too specific.
- Should the image size be part of the image name? eg. someImage_16.png

What is the best naming convention you have found for naming images?

Comment: Hello Mark. I've voted to close your question - I don't think it's a programming question, and it is extremely subjective either way. Besides, a popular option lately is [sprite.png](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) - [example](http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo29.png).

Comment: @Kobi - I though this would be a useful question as programmers have to deal with this issue, day in, day out, and poorly organised images can waste valuable programming time.

Comment: Use star_gold.png and star_black.png, so that you won't need to view the image to know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for a naming convention that predicts future attributes and applications of the file so that you never have to update the file name. That is impossible. You have to rely on your own intuition when you initially name the files.

There is no way around it. If you end up changing either a file or it's application so drastically that the file name no longer accurately reflects its use, then you will either need to keep the misleading name or replace it throughout your files.

Most decent text editors should be able to easily do the latter across multiple files.

The only alternative is to assign names which are not descriptive from the start, which is obviously not a good idea.

Listen to **Kobi** and look into sprites, or if you're averse to sprites, do it the way **Arvin** said for the reasons given.